# Oozie prepare war error Stop oozie first [Oozie v4.3]

Tags: apache, tomcat, oozie

I am trying to migrate Oozie database from derby to MySql. Everything is running fine except when i try to run command

`./oozie-setup.sh prepare-war`

I got the following error

```
  setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"

  ERROR: Stop Oozie first
```

And when I try to run

`./oozied.sh stop`

I get error PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.

I am struggling as I am not getting a way to stop oozie so that I can proceed.

Comment: If you are positive that there is no Oozie process running, then find the "pid" file, delete it, and restart. Just like you would do with any Linux service that relies on a "pid" file somewhere in `/var/run` but does not clean up the file in case of crash.

Comment: BTW it could be that Catalina does *not* store its "pid" file in a `/var/run/` subdir, but in `/tmp` cf. bottom line in https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/AG_Install.html

Answer (score 2):

After a long search and trial i was able to resolve the issue.

You need to delete the pid file which in my case was located in

oozie-4.3.0/oozie-server/temp/oozie.pid

After then you can run `./oozie-setup.sh prepare-war` there will be no error.

Actually issue was that tomcat abroted abnormally and pid file was present there. So removing the file did the job.